# Как при возвращении в активность грубо говоря выполнять onCreate

Tags: java, android

Проблема заключается в том, что при переходе из активности 1 в активность 2, в активности 2 может измениться бд, в свою очередь в первой активности из этой бд заполняется список. И получается так, что при возвращении список уже как бы заполнен и не обновлен. Думал через onResume решить, но слишком костыльно вышло бы. Есть ли решение проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы думаете вызов `onCreate()` не будет костыльным решением?

Самым простым решением, перенесите код работы с БД в `onStart()`. Если по каким-т причинам вам не подходит `onStart()` то вам нужен какой-то флаг, вы можете к примеру воспользоваться методом `startActivityForResult()` при возврате с второй активити в метода `onActivityResult()` вы можете снова обновить ваш UI данными из БД.

Еще вариант это организовать вашу работу с БД по принципу паттерна "Наблюдатель". Т.е. вы в `onStart()` подписались на изменения и всякий раз когда что-то изменилось получаете новые данные.

Но как мне кажется вариант с `onStart()` самый простой, ведь пользователь может свернуть приложение, а в БД что-то поменяется и вам наверное логично было бы показать свежие данные. Но тут надо рассматривать конкретные случаи, серебряных пуль тут нет.

Comment: Перенос в onStart() для меня не работает должным образом. Я вынес работу с бд в метод и вызываю его в onStart, но все так же при возвращении список не обновляется, я потестил с sout и выяснил, что все работает, но адаптер просто не обновляется. Вопрос такой: как мне обновлять его через notifyDataSetChanged() вне onCreate, если я его объявляю сразу в классе активности, то получаю ошибку с контекстом

Comment: Ну а как вы хотите сразу в активити его обновить если у вас еще не создана активити и нет контекста?